# Instantiating Classes Asynchronously

Tags: c#, initialization

So I have some C# code instantiating a class which is exported via a COM object. That particular instantiating call is a blocking call (requires data download from an external source). Therefore, making my C# blocking.

Is it possible to instantiate an object asynchronously?

Comment: Sure.  Spin it up on another thread with a callback, or use `async` `await`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That may not work since it's a COM object...  Hard to know without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using BeginInvoke and EndInovke Asynchronously. Even with COM object, the .EndInovke call is able to retrieve the data. This changes the way the software works fundamentally.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

In general, you can fire up a `Task` to instantiate the object on a background thread.  With C# 5, this can be as simple as:

```
var yourObject = await Task.Run(() => new TheObject());
```

However, since this is a COM object, it's very possible that the object itself may have thread affinity.  If the COM object requires a single threaded apartment thread, you'd need to guarantee an STA thread for it.  If it has thread affinity, then you may need to do it on the UI thread.